# Creating random colour in android with some key (for the same key it should generate same colour)

Tags: java, android, colors

I'm developing a chat application, for this, I'm in need of generation random colour for the user profile picture. But I need to generate the same colour for the same person. I have a unique user id. I don't like to save the colour code after generating the colour code once. So, basically I need an method to get colour code.

```
int getUserColourCode(String userId) {
   //code needed.
   //It should return random colour code (int) with respect to user id.
   //I would like to exclude light shade colours (dark and semi dark colours are preferred).
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you just need a way to convert your string into a 3 (or 4) bytes. For example, you ce get bytes of the string, and take 3 last bytes of it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android/Java: Convert any string to color (hex)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10953423/android-java-convert-any-string-to-color-hex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

int getUserColourCode(String userId) {
    StringBuilder input1 = new StringBuilder();

```
input1.append(userId);
input1=input1.reverse();
String pair[]={"0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"};
char[] character = input1.toString().toCharArray();

for(int i=0;i<character.length;i++)
{
  pair[i]=String.valueOf(character[i]);
}
int color = Color.argb((Integer.parseInt(pair[0]+pair[1])*2)+50, (Integer.parseInt(pair[2]+pair[3])*2)+50, (Integer.parseInt(pair[4]+pair[5])*2)+50, (Integer.parseInt(pair[6]+pair[7])*2)+50);
return color;
```

}

Comment: Thank you, this method gave me an exact solution.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to pass integer as the argument of you function. Instead of `String userId`, please use `int userId`. If you still want to pass String type as the argument, you need to parse it to integer.

Second, you need to define all the colors you want in an array.

Basically you can not use Java Random number build in function because it will always generate new random number, so it will not match with your need.

```
int getUserColourCode(String userId) {
    int id = Integer.parseInt(userId);

    //create integer color as much as you want,
    int[] colors = {Color.BLUE, Color.CYAN, Color.MAGENTA, Color.parseColor("#ff00f8")};

    int colorLength = colors.length - 1;
    int randomNumber = id % colorLength;
    return colors[randomNumber];
}
```

If you pass integer as the type of your argument you can use this:

```
int getUserColourCode(int userId) {

    //create integer color as much as you want,
    int[] colors = {Color.BLUE, Color.CYAN, Color.MAGENTA, Color.parseColor("#ff00f8")};

    int colorLength = colors.length - 1;
    int randomNumber = userId % colorLength;
    return colors[randomNumber];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this you can generate random colors from color code,
But if you need to get color from the user you need shared preference value for the local database to save the color of the user

```
int getUserColourCode(String userId) {
  Random rnd = new Random(); 
   int color = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));      
 return color;
}
```